# Unix while loop shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Hi I am trying to execute the below code in unix but the script is going in infinite loop. Though the code looks to be perfect, i am unable to debug the error:

```
answer=y
while [ "$answer" = "y" ]
do
echo " Enter the word and filename"
read pname flname
grep "$pname" "$flname" > newlist
echo " Enter any more string to be searched (y/n)? "
read anymore
case anymore in
y) answer=y ;;
n) answer=n ;;
esac
done
```

Comment: You lack the dollar sign on the variable.  `case $anymore` pro `case anymore` which just examines the static string "anymore".  Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: also `read` without `-r` will mangle backslashes. Shouldn't be an issue here anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The expression after `case` should be the value of the variable read at previous line :

```
case "$anymore" in
```

instead of :

```
case anymore in
```

**Update :**

As @Jens mentionned, you can omit to double-quote the variable here as *word splitting is not performed on expansions inside `case`* (from http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting#line-106).

Comment: Thanks a lot Kenavoz... Its too bad from my side..i m in the learning phase of unix shell scripting...

Comment: I think you meant to say that the expression after `case` is **not** a variable. In your solution, it's a variable expansion so a value. And you may want to put `$anymore` in quotes to avoid errors.

Comment: Thanks Julien..as sugested by Kenavoz and you, the code is working fine with $anymore..

Comment: Thanks  @JulienLopez, I rephrased.

Comment: @JulienLopez There is no word-splitting performed on the expansion of a case expression. It is one of the few safe places to not bother with double quotes around a single parameter substitution. The other place is in variable assignments, `foo=$bar`.

Comment: @Jens Didn't know that was the case with, well, `case` statements. My bad. It's still a good habit to have especially for beginners.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your comment. I did not remove the quotes here as  [*In either case, quoting anyway will not break anything. So if in doubt, quote!*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting#line-106).